# dired-do-copy in tramp does not go to local when `\ C-j` is pressed. File path stays in the same directory

Tags: dired, tramp, ivy, swiper

I am using dired-do-copy to copy a file from remote using tramp to local.
When Copy file to path is promted. I used `/ C-j` to go to local path but the path stays in the same directory , does not go to local root from remote.

I have also tried `M-x copy-file , M-x gnus-copy-file` and I have having the same issue as above.

- Emacs version - 26.2
- Local Os - MacOs
- Remote server OS(Tramp) - RHEL
- Swiper version - 20190708.1110

Steps to replicate -

1. Login to a remote using tramp
2. Open a directory in remote using dired.
3. Mark a file to copy, and run `M-x dired-do-copy`.
4. Swiper/IVY will prompt the path.
5. Type '/ C-j' to go to local.
6. The path stays the same.
7. Same thing happens to `M-x copy-file` in tramp mode too.

Trying to implement this functionality - https://superuser.com/questions/445564/how-do-you-copy-files-from-a-remote-server-to-a-local-folder-in-emacs-using-dire/445568

**Also is there a way to disable counsel-find-file when dired-do-copy is triggered.**

Comment: Try `//` or `/~/` to get a local path. The remote path will be greyed out.

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE! Please try to only ask one question per post.

Comment: @nega , Thanks for the reply. I am using Ivy. Please see the documentation for `counsel-find-file` here - https://oremacs.com/2019/07/20/ivy-0.12.0/ . '/ C-j' will take me to local root but the functionality does not work `copy-file` or `dired-do-copy` function is triggered.

Comment: Dunno about any of that junk. Normal Emacs works the way I described.

Comment: @user23911 It works for me using Ivy and Counsel.  The UI doesn't make it clear, but the '/' is shown following the full TRAMP path, and is fontified differently.  It becomes much more clear if you do something like '/tmp/'.  The prompt switches so that only the '/tmp' is shown, no more TRAMP path.  If you're getting different behavior it might be something in your setup.  Be sure to try with `emacs -q`

Answer (score 0):

If your minibuffer contains a remote path, you could disable that by typing three slashes "///". See also the Tramp manual https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#File-name-completion

Comment: Hi Micheal, Thanks for the reply. I am sure this works in Vanilla emacs but This is not working when I am using Ivy. I have opened issue here - https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/2205. Also can you please let me know if I can disable Ivy when I run  M-x Copy-file in tramp?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use ivy.